# Interface third-party device to Apple Health?

Tags: siri, health-kit, icloud

[image: Excel rendering power usage over several hours]

I have a smart plug which can monitor the power usage of a medical device while I sleep.   I would like to know if I turn off the device during the night.

I have a proof-of-concept client which can monitor the power draw over time (see graph), and I am looking into using Homebridge to interface it with Siri to see if I can make the "power draw go below 20 watts" trigger an alarm.

The question is, if there is something similar to [Homebridge](https://homebridge.io/) for the Health app, so I can write some glue code that will register this easily like pulse, steps during the day or similar?

I am experienced with Java on most platforms but not with XCode even though I have it running on my Mac.

Comment: Something similar has come up before, see link added on top of your question. As this goes into the realm of software development, specific questions are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you.  I gather from that answer that the way to go is to write an app on a platform officially supported by healthkit. I'll have a closer look on that.

Comment: Very cool. Keep me posted If you make progress. Much has changed since I wrote the answer to the linked question. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220016/possibility-of-getting-healthkit-data-from-third-party-sensors-in-real-time